# Is there any method/way to find out all the functions of some class in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am understanding Laravel(5.1 version although 5.2 now recently comes) framework...and studying it deeply...What I am trying to ask let me elaborate through some example:
 I have created the model named Blog:

```
namespace App; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Blog extends Model {
protected $fillable = ['title','body'];
}
```

Now in my controller I am accessing the function `create()` of this class in my controller store() method like: 
 `public function store(BlogRequest $request)
    {
         $input = Request::all();
         Blog::create($input);
         return redirect('blogs');
    }` 
 As you can see that in above controller method we are accessing the static function/method create() i.e 
 `Blog::create($input)`
 ..so the question is as there are so many other methods exists like `create()` method of a model(Blog) class which extends the Model class...is there any way/strategy/function to find out/know all the functions of this Model Class...

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/ Every Laravel class and their available parameters, functions, methods, etc can be found there.

Comment: @TimLewis Yeah I know this....except this any other coding way like some function which can shows all the functions of some class ....

Comment: It isn't very clear from your question what it is that you want. There is a PHP function `get_class_methods ( $class_name )` which will give you the names of functions in a class, but it will not given any further details. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @Khior...yeah I have just asking to find out the methods of a certain class and nothing....Your commented method is useful... Thank You..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can refer to the [API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/).

For example, I searched for model and found [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html), which is the class your models extend and [there it is](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_create) the create static method.

You can change the Laravel version on the top left and filter for classes, namespaces, interfaces and traits on the top right. Pretty neat!

**Edit:**

You can use the [getMethods method](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) on the [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) to list all available methods for a given class.

For example:

```
$methods = (new ReflectionClass('\App\Blog'))->getMethods();
dd($methods);
```

Comment: Yeah I know this....except this any other coding way like some function which can shows all the functions of some class ...

Comment: Your answer is useful...well I have try this                                                     $methods = get_class_methods('\App\Blog');
      
      foreach($methods as $method) {
          echo $method.'<br>';... }                                                                  it works...Thanking U also...